# Why do some comparable classes in the JDK limit the comparison function to {−1, 0, 1} and some don't?

Tags: java, comparable

The only return value the `java.lang.Comparable<T>` interface explicitly requires is 0 for when `T a` and `T b` are equal. If `a` is less than `b`, then `compare(a, b)` must be negative, not necessarily −1, and `compare(b, a)` must be positive, not necessarily 1.

And yet some comparable classes in the JDK limit the output of the comparison function precisely in that manner, e.g.,

```
scala> (65 to 90).map(n => java.lang.Integer.compare(77, n))
res19: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
```

and some don't, e.g.,

```
scala> ('A' to 'Z').map(ch => java.lang.Character.compare('M', ch))
res10: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 
-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, -13)
```

I was well aware of the somewhat obscure case of RDNs (from `javax.naming.ldap`), but I wasn't expecting to come across this with anything from `java.lang`. I first noticed unrestricted output in `Character.compare()` in the context of a Caesar cypher program in Java, but I find it easier to run "experiments" like these in the local Scala REPL.

When I wrote my implementation of `Fraction`, I followed the example of `Integer` rather than `Character`.

```
scala> val fractA = new fractions.Fraction(65, 128)
fractA: fractions.Fraction = 65/128

scala> val fractB = new fractions.Fraction(90, 128)
fractB: fractions.Fraction = 45/64

scala> fractA to fractB
res20: fractions.FractionRange = 65/128 to 45/64

scala> val fractC = new fractions.Fraction(77, 128)
fractC: fractions.Fraction = 77/128

scala> res20.map(_.compare(fractC))
res21: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

scala> res20.map(fractC.compare)
res22: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)

scala> res19 == res22
res23: Boolean = true
```

In the case of `Fraction`, it's no problem to implement it like this. Actually, it would be more trouble to not do it like this. The numerator and denominator are of type `long`, so there could be problems if the numerator of the difference is just a little outside the range of `int`. By using `Long.signum()`, I reduce the possibility of wrong results to a small set of edge cases.

Since `char` maps to half the range of `int`, I suppose it's easier for `String` to not restrict the result of `compare()` to {−1, 0, 1}.

```
scala> "Hello, World!" compare "Hello, world?"
res30: Int = -32
```

Here I'm guessing that if no surrogates are involved, or maybe even if surrogates are involved, it's easier to just run `Character.compare()` on each character of the `String` until either the first nonzero result or reaching the end.

Is this the explanation, that one should do whatever is easiest and gives the correct results? Or is there a deeper reason to restrict to signum of the difference in some comparable classes and not others?

Comment: Well you answered your own question - the naive subtraction method only works for chars and smaller so classes that deal with anything bigger have to use explicit values. (It's also not some small edge cases, it's a quarter of all numbers)

Comment: @Voo Maybe, but perhaps someone who's worked on a JDK might have some insights to elaborate or at least confirm...

Comment: You think it's just a maybe that JDK engineers didn't want to have code that was wrong 25% of the time?

Comment: @Voo No, I think maybe there's a somewhat common situation in which a limited result set is beneficial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Main answer

Because implementations are free to choose whatever positive or negative value suits them best. The [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) says about the return value:

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
> than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

One might argue whether this spec was a wise decision or not, but that's the way it has been defined. So, never rely on the results of a comparison being only -1, 0, or 1, even if experimenting with one specific Java version shows that behaviour - it might change with the next release.

### Implementations answer

This answer is already found in your question, mainly.

There are two typical ways of implementing comparison:

- Integer Subtraction: that gives results not limited to -1, 0, 1. The code is simple, elegant and fast. But there can be overflow, e.g. for values 2_000_000_000 - (-2_000_000_000) mathematically is 4_000_000_000, but with 32-bit int the result shows as -294_967_296, falsely implying that 2_000_000_000 is less than -2_000_000_000. To avoid overflow, int subtraction works for numbers up to roughly +/- 1_000_000_000.
- Decision: this typically needs an `if ... else if ... else` construct where the return values for the three cases are explicitly given. Then it's a natural choice to use -1, 0, and 1, and I don't know of an implementation using other fixed values.

So, subtraction is a valid solution for byte and char, where an int-based subtraction has enough reserve bits that overflow can't happen. So, it's more likely for those datataypes and their derivatives to show values outside of -1, 0, and 1.

### Fraction class

You're wrting about a `Fraction` class you're implementing. If two Fraction instances can be created, not giving an exception, I'd require the `compareTo()` method to give correct results, always. As comparison of fractions is a tricky thing, overflows of intermediate results can be expected. So, I'd recommend to create some test cases with numerators and/or denominators close to the validity limits (whatever you define them to be).

Another approach to avoid overflow would be switching to the unlimited-range `BigInteger` type, but that might have a performance impact.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. For my particular application, as long as the arithmetic functions of `Fraction` work correctly for numerators and denominators in the range of `int`, I'm not really worried about edge cases involving `Long.MIN_VALUE`, `Long.MAX_VALUE` or numbers in that vicinity.